# MySQL: Select problems

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, distinct

Have two tables:

```
wes - contains 8000 rows, with 2000 distinct masternames (mastername is a column in wes)
wem - contains 2100 rows, with 2100 distinct names (name is a column in wem)
```

I'm trying to get the names that exist in wem, but not as masternames in wes:

```
SELECT name FROM wem WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT mastername FROM wes)
```

But for some reason my query doesn't return any rows, even though there are ~100 names in wem that doesn't exist as masternames in wes.

Any ideas about what is going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the type of columns in both tables?

Comment: What collation is the columns?

Comment: Your sql statement seems to be correct. I think you should check again if the names are really not in the wes table and are really committed in the wem table. It may happen something like you inserted new records to wem, did not commit and on a different session you try your SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there are no NULLS in the sub-select?

Try `SELECT mastername FROM wes WHERE mastername IS NULL`

If there are, your query will return 0 rwows.

Adjust to:

```
SELECT NAME FROM wem
WHERE NAME NOT IN (SELECT mastername FROM wes WHERE mastername IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

I usually avoid using `NOT IN` in such situation; try below query :

```
SELECT NAME
FROM   wem a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                  FROM   wes b
                  WHERE  a.name = b.mastername)
```